# How to handle INCOMING HTTP/S GET requests in my Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, get

I am implementing SMS paying sistem. User sends message with some code and buys some features on my site.

But to do that I need to handle 2 HTTP/S GET requests and get information from them.

First request is like this :

```
http://www.yourpage.com/sms/receive.php?sms-id=%sms-id%&operator-id=%operator-id%&from=%from%&to=%to%&text=%text%
```

How would be easiest way to handle theese requests and based on them make changes in my database ?

SO far I googled "HOW to handle HTTP/S requests in my Rails app" I got zero usefull sources. I got only sources that explains how to make HTTP/S requests but not how to handle them and use.

Is there any suggestion to this problem ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean HTTPS, as "secure HTTP"? Then the URL is wrong and it's not going to make an HTTPS request.

Comment: You can create routes for it - get 'your_path_for_request', to: 'your_controller#your_action'

Comment: @D-side One or other. At this point that is not important. I want to know how can I handle GET requests to my application. Idea is that third party server sends theese GET requests to my site, but I need to give response to them. How can I do that ?

Comment: @SergeySokolov Now I start to get idea. But how then I can read that request from my controller ? Do I need some gem for that ?

Comment: You can read all of params (sms_id etc) in params array in you controller (by default rails way)

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds They're no different from HTTP requests. The only thing is that your server needs to be configured to accept HTTPS. Typically in production it's `nginx` as a load balancer. There are plenty of guides out there about that. That implies that you have your server configured with a key signed by a trusted party.

Comment: As a note, do not make any DB changes on a GET request and make sure you're authenticating the requests to the `receive` end point otherwise anybody can spam your URL.

Comment: @RobinFisher There is only two IP adresses from what I will make changes to my db. There is no other way around :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Rails controller handles incoming HTTP requests. To generate one, run the following from the command line:
`rails generate controller sms receive`
This will create an `SmsController.rb` file with a function named `receive`.
In that function, do something like this:
`def receive
  sms_id=params[:sms_id]
  ... do something ...
end`

and I'd recommend [learning Rails basics](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) :)